# Excel percent over 100%

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two cells both of which have this formula in them

=IF(ISERROR(100%-E18)," ",ABS(100%-E18))

The sells are named percentage drop and percentage increase, I want it so if the percentage is over 100% percentage increase says for example 5% and percentage drop is left blank. Likewise if the percentage is under 100% the cell percentage drop will be for example 5% and the other cell will be left blank.

Help please!

Thanks

Comment: What is the value type of E18?

Comment: It is a percentage, I was thinking of using another ISERROR with > or < 100 but it wont accept

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using % when using just a number would do the same? Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 100% = 1 in excel you can use this formula for increase

`=IFERROR(IF(E18>=1,E18-1,""),"")`

and this for drop

`=IFERROR(IF(E18<=1,1-E18,""),"")`

Format cell as %

If E18 = 100% both cells will show zero

Comment: Thanks Barry only problem is i need it to be an absolute number so instead of say 5% if the value in E18 is 95%, I am getting -5% which i dont want.

Comment: never worry got it sorted, that worked fine. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Drop:

```
=IF(E18<100%,E18-100%,"")
```

Increase:

```
=IF(E18>100%,100%-E18,"")
```

If the percentage is exactly 100, both cells will be blank.